# Read records from different topics in lockstpe

Tags: apache-kafka

The use case I'm trying to solve is this: I have two topics "letters" and "numbers". What I want is to read records from these topics in lockstep. So say a producer pushed to "letters" the records "a", "b", "c" and a producer pushed to numbers the records "1" and "2". I want my consumer to get ("a", "1"), ("b", "2"). It will not get "c" since there's no matching number.